# Make it clear that deleted questions also count when warning people about the question ban

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

Every so often someone goes over to meta to ask about a warning they get when posting a question, and say they only have one or two bad questions. What follows shortly after is a moderator/staff member/10k user tells them that they have many deleted questions that also count for the ban, and finally the question is closed as a duplicate of a FAQ-type question.

Could we change the warning displayed when close to the question ban to tell right away that deleted questions count, with the "deleted questions" being a link to the user's recently deleted questions page ?

Comment: That might work for those where the bad deleted questions aren't that far in the past, at least. At least for those who bother to read.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Look... If you've asked a dozen questions scoring 0 or less... Ignoring multiple warnings pleading with you to read /help/how-to-ask and edit your existing questions, cheerfully deleted your questions after ignoring criticism as soon as someone caves and gives you the code you're looking for...

...then it is EXTREMELY UNLIKELY that you're suddenly going to GET RELIGION and go back and edit all those questions you treated with disdain.

Trust me - I've been guiding folks through exactly this scenario for years now. You tell 'em, "you've one chance - go edit your questions such that they make sense", and they reply, "I have an assignment due".

Deleted questions are, within a slim margin of error, **never the problem.** The problem is the other crappy questions with nondescript titles and vague problem statements. If you can't even be bothered to edit *those*, then what hope do you have with the dregs?

Comment: Perhaps we should look at this as less of a "reform new users" issue than as a "keep new users from clogging meta with crap" issue?

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at, @Kevin. Hundreds of users hit this every day; the volume of related meta posts is tiny in comparison. Unless you mean "stop telling the handful who come to meta to look at their deleted questions", in which case I wholly agree.

Comment: Perhaps, but how does it compare to the *total* volume of meta posts?  If it's a significant proportion, it may still be worth going after.

Comment: I doubt it. Count 'em!

Answer (score 1):

I know I've complained about some of these policies before, but it's worth observing that questions from far in the past, with lots of answers and upvotes, are sometimes deleted because they don't fit a current mod's idea of what should be the correct type of question.  Some caution should probably be exercised with bans and other actions based on deletions.

Comment: If they are deleted sufficiently long after being posted (I think 2 months, might be 3 or so), the post being deleted is quite irrelevant for bans or throttling.

Comment: My apologies but I've had some trouble pinning down how this all works.  I appear to be 'at risk' due to some deleted questions but I have no recollection as to what they are or why they were deleted.  It seems to me that parts of this process are more about 'keeping score' than actually help people improve.  I have had a suspicion for a while that SO is not for me but It seems I've got to grapple with it as Google had outsourced part of their customer service here.

Comment: @RFlack: Which shows two misconceptions: SO is not about handholding, but about good questions and answers useful for a long time. Also, I somehow doubt they outsourced their "customer service", the outcry on meta would have been remarkable. What they outsourced is only their developer support, helping people program using their APIs and platforms, instead of managing accounts, booking their services, announcing new exciting products and opportunities and all those other core customer support things.

Comment: @deduplicator: I think I said they had outsourced some of their customer support. I didn't mean to infer all of it.  Isn't GAE aimed at 'hobbyists' as well as pro developers?  ( I am obviously in the former camp not the latter) .

Comment: @RFlack You don't have to be an expert software engineer to ask questions on SO. You just have to 1) show that you did at least some research to try to solve the problem before asking the question and 2) word your questions such that it's clear what you're asking (and such that what you're asking is sufficiently narrow and objectively-answerable.)